# Отсортировать строки по количеству чисел, являющихся полным квадратом(4,9,16..)

Tags: c#, linq

Не разбираюсь в linq, но по заданию нужно сделать: *Отсортировать строки по количеству чисел, являющихся полным квадратом(4,9,16..)*
Я примерно понимаю, что выглядеть должно вот так:  `matrix = matrix.OrderByDescending(x => x.Where(y => y "и здесь условия, но не могу его написать")).ToArray();`

Comment: `where(x=> (int)sqrt(x) * (int)sqrt(x) == x) ?`

Answer (score 1):

Представим, что матрица - это массив массивов.

```
var matrix = new[]
{
    new[] {10, 10, 10, 10},
    new[] {9, 9, 9, 9},
};

var sortedMatrix = matrix
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count(IsPerfectSquare));

private static bool IsPerfectSquare(int x) =>
(int) Math.Sqrt(x) * (int) Math.Sqrt(x) == x;
```